# Not clear why "start" is assigned/gives reference at line 1

Tags: java, linked-list

This is a issue of single linked list implementation.

Say, A class `Node` is defined. 
Now, for operations another class `LinkedList` is defined. We are going to add element at start position.

```
class LinkedList {
    protected Node start;
    protected Node end;
    public int size;

    public LinkedList() {
        start = null;
        end = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    //method for insert at start
    public void insertAtStart(int value) {
        Node nptr = new Node (value, null);
        size++;

        if (start == null) {
            start = nptr;
            end = start; //Line 1
        }
    }

    // others method(omitted here)
}
```

I was thinking,  what would happen if we assign `nptr` itself to `end` in *Line 1*? I am not getting clear in that issue.

Comment: Nothing. It's the same thing.

Comment: Please format your code properly and remove the syntax error(s) (`if(start=null)` is definitively one). Other than that, there is no difference between assigning `start` or `nptr` to `end` sine they are the same (you assigned `nptr` to `start` right before assigning `start` to `end`...).

Comment: What is the issue in the code, i couldn't get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this line:

```
start = nptr;
```

the variable `start` holds the *reference* to the same object as `nptr`, i.e. the object created during:

```
Node nptr = new Node (value, null);
```

So it doesn't matter if you call `end = start` or `end = nptr` as `end` will contain the same reference afterwards; `nptr`, `end` and `start` will all point to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the end reference variable should be updated only for first call of  `insertAtStart(int val)` to maintain the reference to the end node.

if you assign `nptr` itself to `end` in Line 1, the end reference variable will have the reference to newly added node (Which is the first node of the list).